# Do dimensions of the product $q_k p_k$ always equal to that of angular momentum?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, momentum, dimensional-analysis

I know that generalised coordinates and their conjugate momentum may or may not have the same dimensions as to that of length and linear momentum, but in one book I saw it was mentioned that their product must always have the dimensions of angular momentum.

Is it true?

Comment: If you like this question, you may also enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28957/2451) &  [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153298/2451) posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lagrangian $L$ has dimensions of energy, and $$ p_i=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}, $$ so (because $\dot{q}$ has dimension of $[q]/T$) $$ \frac{[q]}{T}\cdot[p]=E, \\ [q]\cdot[p]=E\cdot T. $$

And $E\cdot T$ is precisely the dimension of action/angular momentum.